# What can I use as dog kennel roofing?

Tags: roof, roofing

I have a 10' x 10' chain link kennel (standard round tube).

I'm looking at roofing options, and all of the kennel covers that I've found so far are tarps. I have concerns over the durability and snow load of tarps in winter (I live in Maine).

Are there any materials that would be more durable and affordable?

Comment: Whatever you decide to do, please make sure it is safe and secure. Snow loads in Maine on a flat roof are 50-100 psf, depending on where you are. And that does **not** include a safety factor. Obviously a dog kennel doesn't need to be bomb-proof, but you don't want anyone to get hurt.

Comment: is psf pounds per sq foot ?

Comment: Yes, psf == pounds per square foot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've lived in Canada and now the Midwest where snow can get good depth at either place. We've always used tarp reinforced with additional cross beams and tied with hard ties, but some off the shelf walmart tarp won't cut it. You need "heavy duty" tarp rated for all-weather use. You can generally expect reliability out of it for around 10 years.

We tried the corrugated roofing and noticed three things that made us switch. On the rainy days the sound it makes drove both the animals and ourselves nuts. When it hails, they get beat up really quick and easy. especially if they have a couple years on them and have gotten brittle in the case of the plastic types...and on the windy days, it becomes a great big sail that can really put some test to your anchors if they aren't rock solid. Where as the tarps somehow seem to have more "give" to them.

Anyway, it will all come down to what you're dealing with in your particular area and the type of weather. I would ask a neighbor or buddy to see what's worked best for them.

Answer (score 1):

How about [Corrugated Roofing Panels](http://www.lowes.com/Roofing-Gutters/Roof-Panels-Accessories/Roof-Panels/_/N-1z10lsp/pl#!)?

[image]

It's available in many different materials, easy to install, and is usually about $15 - $30 per panel. You'll need some underlying support structure, but how much and how strong it has to be depends on the amount of snow in your area.

Comment: I was considering those as well - corrugated metal or the plastic, but have concerns with the flat roof design and snow load. If I engineer a peak, then I need a ridge, etc.